# How to count "reliably" 300 seconds time in perl?

Tags: perl, time

How can I make a 5 minutes timeout?

My program is doing this:

```
# I need to try something every 3 seconds, for at most 5 minutes
$maxtime = time() + (5 * 60);
$success = 0;
while (($success == 0) && (time() < $maxtime)) {
  $success = try_something();
  sleep (3) if ($success == 0);
}
```

The problem: this program runs just after boot. The embedded system that it runs has no rtc/clock battery. The clock starts at Jan/1/2000, then in the first minute it runs, it gets network and ntp sets the clock to the updated clock, making the loop exit before the 5 minutes timeout.

Which is the right way to "count 5 minutes" inside a perl script, even if the system clock is changed by other external program?

Comment: What about using the system uptime?  There's a Perl module that returns you an `int` value representing the uptime in seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using the alarm function would make sense here.

```
{
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
     warn "Ooops! timed out, exiting";
     exit(100); # give whatever exit code you want
  };

  ## setup alaram
  alarm( 5 * 60 );
  my $success = 0;
  until($success) {
    $success = try_something()
       or sleep 3;
  }

  ## deactivate alarm if successful
  alarm(0);
}
```

Comment: nice! the alarm() does it well. it is not affected by external clock changes. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If try_something() takes a disregardable amount of time, you could just loop 100 times.  Or if the system is busy enough that your sleep often takes more than 3 seconds, `use Time::HiRes 'sleep';` and add up the return values of sleep until it gets to 300.

If not, then perhaps something like this:

```
my $last_time = my $start_time = time();
while () {
    try_something() and last;
    my $time = time();
    # system clock reset? (test some limit that is more than try_something could ever take)
    if ( $time - $last_time > 86400 ) {
        $start_time += $time - $last_time;
    }
    $last_time = $time;
    sleep( List::Util::min( 3, $start_time + 300 - $time ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use one of the monotonic timers; for example the `select` and `poll` timeout uses that.

```
select undef, undef, undef, 5*60;
```

or

```
use IO::Poll;
my $poll = IO::Poll->new;

$poll->poll(5*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `sleep` is the actual number of seconds slept. You could check this value and ignore any values that were unusually large:

```
$success = 0;
$slept = 0;
while (($success == 0) && ($slept < 300)) {
  $success = try_something();
  if ($success == 0) {
      $n = sleep 3;
      if ($n <= 3) {
          $slept += $n;
      } else {
          # looks like the clock just got updated
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a real solution, because try_something() takes about 5 seconds to complete.

Comment: Then wrap `try_something` in some time checks, e.g., `$t=time;$success=try_something();$t2=time-$t;if($t2<100){$slept+=$t2}`